# Android development: How to add a gallery of images from the internet

Tags: android, gallery, swipe

What I am trying to do is an app similar to iFunny or any funny picture apps. I want to be able to get a list of direct image links from the internet and then display the image one by one on a gallery. The user can swipe to see the next picture. What should I add to be able to do this. I never worked with a gallery before. Thank you.

Comment: Please post what you've done so far. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set `Uri` directly to the `ImageView` of the Gallery. As follows...

```
Uri myUrl=Uri.parse(ImageUrlArray[Position]);
imageView.setImageURI(myUrl);
```

Do it in the `getView` method of the `ImageAdapter` you used.